# Getting multiple responses in teams bot with MS bot framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, azure-language-understanding

I build a conversation flow with MS bot framework and integrated with both directline and MSteams channels. In directline the bot works as expected but in teams I am getting multiple respones after clicking button in adaptive card.
In console I am getting following error

> [BotCardService::onButtonClicked_messageback()] sendInvoke failed: {"statusCode":502,"headers":{"cache-control":"no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache","content-length":"62","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","contextid":"tcid=0,server=msgapi-production-eus-azsc2-4-26,cv=YdgpimU6xke+FCgXbKUINg.0","pragma":"no-cache"},"errorMessage":"Error Code: 1008 ","errorCode":1008,"request":{}}

Can someone help me on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant sections of code that are causing the error?

Comment: Hi, Could you please share more details like code snippet that's causing the error.

Comment: Thank you prasad and billoverton for your response. I am able to find the problem why i am getting multiple messages. This is an issue with msteams with adaptive card. It has a timeout of 10 secs so when it's not getting the response,teams retry the activity again and process the same activity. Now what I need is how can we trigger the waterfall model proactively? Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @YagnesYagne, You can refer [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) bot samples to get an idea on 'how to implement a conversation flow' . Also if you want to implement a sequential flow using dialogs you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)